# Kendo-Angular2: How to enable checkbox only selection mode in kendo-grid with auto-generated columns

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to display a `kendo-grid` with auto generated columns and enable checkbox only selection mode.

The following creates a `kendo-grid` with Auto-generated columns and works fine, [(plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOUNBUXKO9eBObJNuW9s?p=preview)

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true">
</kendo-grid>
```

However when I try to add a checkbox selection column, only the checkbox selection column is being displayed. [(plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z183jQip6XYVUs0KHFAG?p=preview)

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true">
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column showSelectAll="true"><kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

It works when the columns are specified, [(plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Vl1WvrLqqvPpknIy5E7?p=preview)

```
<!-- works -->
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true">
      <kendo-grid-checkbox-column showSelectAll='true'></kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="Id" title="ID"></kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="CompanyName" title="Company Name"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

How can I make it work when the columns are not known in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the objects in the object array have the same properties, `Object.keys()` could be applied on the first object in the array to get the property names which can then be passed to the `field` property of `kendoGridColumn` component.

Something like this

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="{checkboxOnly: true}">
  <ng-container *ngIf="gridData?.length > 0">
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column showSelectAll="true">
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(gridData[0])">
        <kendo-grid-column [field]="key" [title]="key">
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</kendo-grid>
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-grid-select-all-dynamic-data)